# How to use c to strip html tags and images from webpage to file

Tags: linux, terminal, stdin

How would i go about using c to write a program to strip a webpage inputted in via the terminal in Linux and remove all the HTML tags and images and put the remaining content into a file.

I am just confused on how to get the webpage from the terminal.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand: what does a terminal have to do with a web page? If you want to get the contents of a web page from your C program, use a networking library such as libcurl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can get a web page in terminal by various programs such as `curl`, `wget`, `aria2c` etc. Download webpage using those program use write your C program to strip tags.
- If you want to download webpage using C. You can use [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl). To get sample code how to use [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl) to download `http://stackoverflow.com` use the following command.

  ```
  curl --libcurl downloadstackoverflow.c  http://stackoverflow.com
  ```

  This will generate a file `downloadstackoverflow.c` which contains sample code.
- This is a simple program that strips tags from html. It does not support tags in quotes `"`. But you should get the idea.

  ```
  int main() {
     int in_tag = 0;
     char c;

     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
         if (c == '<' || c == '>') {
             in_tag = (c == '<') ? 1 : 0;
         } else {
             if (!in_tag) {
                 putchar(c);
             }
         }
     } }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use wget to download de page from the terminal. Use something like "wget http://www.google.com -O filename.html". It will download the page to the file "filename.html".